# Embedded C vs. General Purpose C

Tags: c, embedded

Can somebody list all the differences between Embedded C for intel 8051 and General Purpose C?. Where can I find the standards of Embedded C?

Comment: There is no one "embedded C for Intel 8051".  The 8051 _is_ a bad fit for the C programming language, which make it tempting to write "C-ish" languages for it -- and various people have done just that over the years.  However, there is no one way: various compilers for that chip treat the problem differently.  If the particular tool chain you are using is well documented, those documents will have a **large** and carefully written section on those differences.

Comment: Well there's some icky non-standard C dialect for 8051 where the XOR operator `^` has a different meaning. I think it was invented by Keil(?). Luckily, all sane people stopped using 8051 well over 20 years back, so we don't have to worry about it any longer. Questions about 8051 belong on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/, they have no place on an engineering site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear distinction between "Embedded C" and "General Purpose C".

What's generally referred to as "Embedded C" are the features of C compilers that specifically generate code for embedded systems. Those features are usually a subset or an extension of "Standard C".

"Embedded C" might also refer to coding standards and guidelines that limit "Standard C" to a subset of features more suitable for embedded systems. For example, MISRA-C defines such a subset to promote safe and secure embedded software that takes the special requirements of embedded systems into account, e. g. limited dynamic memory of many embedded systems compared to non-embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard for embedded C which has extensions to use with embedded processors at:

https://www.iso.org/standard/51126.html

Most embedded software engineers however use Kernighan and Ritchie C90 or C99 standard without stdlib of C. Many engineers prefer coding guidelines with which you can remove unwanted and undefined behavior in C programs. In embedded systems, preventing undefined behavior of a system is a strict requirement.These coding guidelines are different for different embedded processors but generally they seem to overlap.

Some industries like automotive and aviation, industrial automation use different standards which have been customized for individual applications.